# Where are the opacity key frames for masks?

Tags: keyframes, masking, dopesheet

When animating a mask's opacity, you cannot find the keyframes in the dopesheet. Is in another place instead?

I've found [this bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T50061) but it's not clear if is there a solution or if it's even a bug.

Comment: That bug report is still open and it hasn't yet been fixed, which means it still needs to be looked at by a developer. I suggest creating an account on the developer.blender website and subscribing to the bug report so you will be notified when anyone new comments.

Comment: I do have an account, thanks for the tip Ray I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

While the bug is fixed (if it ever does), you can use a math node set to multiply to control the opacity of the mask. Animate the values from 1 (full opacity) to 0 (no opacity). Those keyframes will show up on the graph editor or the dopesheet.

[image]

Animating the values

Comment: Thanks Cegaton, I already knew that. But it does not response my question :( The problem here is that I have a bunch of mask layers. In that case managing the opacity in composition is a mess.